# Kubernetes route

Tags: kubernetes

I want to configure the interface of master node and slave node. After running the master node and joining slave node, master shows:

```
vagrant@kube4local:~$ sudo kubectl get nodes
NAME         STATUS    AGE       VERSION
kube4local   Ready     6m        v1.7.1
```

Why is my slave node is not added in cluster ? I tried to change the interface, but still it does not help.

**ip route master:**

```
vagrant@kube4local:~$ ip r
default via 192.168.56.104 dev enp0s8
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
10.32.0.0/12 dev weave  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.32.0.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.104
```

**ip route slave:**

```
vagrant@kube5local:~$ ip r
default via 192.168.56.105 dev enp0s8
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.105
```

Comment: I suggest you include much more details in your question. A good start would be the method you used to deploy the cluster (commands, configuration, command line arguments to kube components) and any logs that seem relevant. In this this case `kubelet` and `kube-apiserver` logs would be useful (use `journalctl`/`docker logs` to get these - depending on your setup).

Answer (score 0):

I think your route is wrong. both servers default get should should be same IP. but your output shows different IP.

Not sure about your network setup, check and see 192.168.56.105 is your default gateway.

> default via 192.168.56.105 dev enp0s8

I use this script to correct my default route. update correct getway address.

```
cat correct_default_route.sh
#!/bin/bash

export GW='192.168.56.1'

echo "Checking route : $(date)"

if $( ip route |grep  -q '^default via 10.0.2.2 dev' ); then
        echo "Removing vagrant defualt route : $(date)"
        ip route delete default via  10.0.2.2
fi

if ! $( ip r |egrep -q "^default .* ${GW}" ); then
        ip route add default via $GW
fi

ip r

echo "Done : $(date)"
exit 0
```

vagarnt network config.

```
VM_NETMASK = "255.255.255.0"
VM_BRIDGE = ENV["VAGRANT_BRIDGE"] || "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165"
ip='192.168.1.20'
host.vm.network "public_network", bridge: VM_BRIDGE, ip: ip, :auto_config => "false", :netmask => VM_NETMASK
```

Comment: Excuse me, but very new to routing (( I tried to edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces`, and add comment interface `enp0s3`, edit file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, and add `supersede routers 192.168.56.105;` on both servers, then restart, and my ip have changed to a 192.168.56.101 192.168.56.102 accordingly.What am I doing wrong? Plz, help..

Comment: you can find the default from our host machine. usally it will  be first ip for the default gateway `192.168.56.1`.  you can confirm this from your host machine `ipconfig` or `netstat -rn` commad output. I will edit my response with script I use.

Comment: Unfortunately, your script didn't help. The servers perfectly see each other, ssh works, 'kubeadm join slave' successfully completes, but 'kubectl get nodes' show slave node in status NotReady(

Comment: what is the cni software your using flannel or wave?

Comment: On master node i used `kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"`

Comment: ok, I think your cluster configured with primary interface. run this command  and see cluster IP is in 10 network or 192 network `kubectl  cluster-info`. can you post the output of this command?

Comment: `vagrant@kube4local:~$ sudo kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.56.104:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.56.104:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns/proxy` Cluster IP is in 192 network, because i run `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.104`, otherwise the slave node does not connect

Comment: And yet I think the problem is in the interface. `ipconfig` shows that my default gateway  `192.168.100.1`, but when i run your script get error that `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

Comment: lets check ow vagrant network is configured. I used bridge network. can you check your settings. `VM_NETMASK = "255.255.255.0"
VM_BRIDGE = ENV["VAGRANT_BRIDGE"] || "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165"
ip='192.168.1.20'
host.vm.network "public_network", bridge: VM_BRIDGE, ip: ip, :auto_config => "false", :netmask => VM_NETMASK  `

Comment: Sorry, i was on vacation. You know. the use of flannel helped me. But after adding slaves, i do a restart, so that they become ready